# Filtering JSON to get specific results

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using the Quotes on Design API  https://quotesondesign.com/api-v4-0/to show random quotes by designers on my site.

However, **the idea is to show quotes but only by specific designers randomly**.

My code below does not work. Any idea why and how should i go about it to get the desired results.

```
    $.ajaxSetup(
{  cache: false}
);

function newQuote(){
  $.getJSON('https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=', function(json,data){
 // Filter to return quotes by Steve Jobs only
    return json.filter(function(data){
      return (data[0].title == "Steve Jobs")
    });
    // add the quote(data[0].content) to my page.
    $('.quote_text').html(data[0].content);
  });

}
// get a new quote everytime i click the button (.message_btn)
$(document).ready(function(){
  newQuote();
  $('.message_btn').on('click',newQuote).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: The code doesn't not work in term of what? First all, your query string is set to random `filter[orderby]=rand` and return post per page as 1 `filter[posts_per_page=1`, so it only return one random post and of course it is not necessary match the `title=='steve jobs'`.  Read more on [WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) on how the filter works.

Comment: `$('.quote_text').html(data[0].content)` will never run because you return before that line of code is reached.

Comment: Hi Mikael,  the aim is to get quotes from the API, but only from specific people(Steve Jobs, Jonathan Ive etc). After that only post one quote per page randomly. That is:- a quote by either steve Jobs or Jonathan Ive when i refresh the page. Is there a way a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. It appears that the server is using Wordpress legacy API. I've changed the request URL to randomly request for one of the titles in the array.

```
function newQuote() {
    var titles = ["Steve Jobs", "Jonathan Ive", "Frank Zappa", "Kent Beck"];
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * titles.length);
    var url = "https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[name]=" + titles[index];

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

        console.log("data length: " + data.length);
        console.log("returned  title: " + data[0].title);

        if (data.length)
            $('.quote_text').html(data[0].content + " - " + data[0].title);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks H77, is there a way to filter such that i only get objects that have title set to a specific group of people (Steve Jobs, Jonathan Ive, etc). after that randomly select and display only one quote and its title (.content and .title)?

Comment: Hi @H77 , it works exactly as you said, i have to click the (.message_btn) quite a number of times. No results until the title matches one of the titles in the allowed list.  Not what i was hoping for though. still trying to figure it out.Any other ideas? Thanks a Mill for your help.

Comment: @ochiengbenja I think I understand what you mean now. I've changed the code to randomly request a post for one of the allowed titles from the server.